# C: Array initialization segfaults depending on size and call to printf()

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, printf

Another student asked me what could be wrong with his C code. I successfully reproduced the erroneous behavior and have completely no idea why this segfaults. Consider this tiny C programm:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int N = 590;
    double A[N][N];
    double B[N][N];
    double C[N][N];
    printf("done");
}
```

- Set `N` to a value <= 590:
  This runs without errors, with or without output.
- set `N` to a value > 590:

  - Runs flawlessy with output line removed.
  - Compile and run with output: *segmentation fault*

What's the reason for this? Can anybody explain?

Comment: Well, that's approximatively 2 MB of stack storage... That's huge ! Please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program

Comment: @user1417475 Segmentation? 64k segments? In which decade do you live?

Comment: @user1417475: Any document about assembly language programming that's more than a few years old is probably more harmful than helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to allocate more memory than it's available on the stack which causes **stack overflow**. Usually it is much better to allocate huge arrays like that dynamically by using `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`. Don't forget to free this memory by calling `free` when you finish with it :)

These questions will help you too:
[C/C++ maximum stack size of program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825964/1168156)
[Segmentation Fault on creating an array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7541415/1168156)
[Segmentation Fault When Using Variable To Initiate Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7987672/1168156)

Answer (score 2):

The amount of stack you have available to your app is very system dependent, and automatic variables (such as your double arrays) consume stack space. Calling a function requires additional stack space (for its variables, and housekeeping such as saved registers and a return point). You're going off the end of your stack and trying to access memory you're forbidden to access.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a stack overflow. However I can reproduce it here both with and without the `printf` with VC++. My best guess is that the operation of pushing arguments to the `printf` on the stack causes the error to manifest itself. Does it still happen if you call a function that takes no paramters?

Comment: You're right about pushing arguments on stack. If I introduce a new function without parameters the error doesn't appear.