# getting SIGSEGV for large values of n(above 500000)

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int l;
int check(int m[][l],int a,int r,int c,int e)
{
    int t,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<c;i++)
    {
        if(m[a][i]==e)
            return 1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<c;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<r;j++)
        {
            if(a!=j)
            {
                if(m[a][i]==m[j][i]&&m[a][i]!=-1)
                {
                    m[a][i]=-1;
                    return check(m,j,r,c,e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    int i,j;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(t;t>0;t--)
    {
        l=0;
        int n,e,a,b,x,y;
        scanf("%d%d%d%d",&n,&e,&a,&b);
        int m[e][n];
        l=n;
        for(i=0;i<e;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                m[i][j]=-1;
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<e;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
            for(j=0;j<((n-y)/x)+1;j++)
            {
                m[i][y+(j*x)]=y+(j*x);
            }
        }
        int v,g=0;
        for(i=0;i<e;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(m[i][j]==a)
                {
                    v=check(m,i,e,n,b);
                    g++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(v==1)
        {
            printf("It is possible to move the furniture.\n");
        }
        else if(v==0||g==0)
            printf("The furniture cannot be moved.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> "I'm getting the correct answer for value of n<=50000, when i give more values i'm  getting runtime error"
>   "i have written a code for "http://www.spoj.pl/problems/SCRAPER/"..
>   when i run it in ideone, i got the answers as "runtime error" for more 'n' values

Comment: wow that's a lot of 1 letter variable names!

Comment: This code is unreadable.

Comment: You are using a VLA, and perhaps `50000` is too big a size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to allocate more memory than it's available on the stack which causes **stack overflow**. Usually it is much better to allocate huge arrays like that dynamically by using `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

Check this question: [C: Array initialization segfaults depending on size and call to printf()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10983084/1168156)

Comment: Just a side-note. The OP is using VLAs and `gcc` stores them on the stack. But there is no compulsion on part of the compiler to do this. Other compilers might wish to store VLAs elsewhere ( heap etc )

Comment: thanks a lot. And can you one tell me how to initialize a 2D array dynamically using malloc,calloc or realloc?

Comment: @user1487765: Allocate an array of pointers first (first dimension) and then allocate an array representing each row and assign its address to each of those pointers (second dimension).

Answer (score 0):

Your array may be stored onto the stack, and the stack is usually smaller than the heap. Try to allocate your array dynamically (`malloc`, `calloc`, `free`).

Comment: thanks a lot. And can any one tell me how to initialize a 2D array dynamically using malloc,calloc or realloc

Answer (score 0):

When you write "int m[e][n]", the real space of the array is 1! The space of array is defiend when compiled, when 'e' 'n' are both 0. You have to use **macro** as the array's length, such as m[1000][1000]. And you need to make sure that e<1000.

Comment: No, it's a variable length array, standardised since C99. It'll be allocated at run time.